# Porqué mysql no filtra las fechas?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un programa en tkinter que saca la fecha de un tkinter dateentry y la usa cómo filtro en un query de myql. El problema es que a pesar de que ambos fromatos de fechas son compatibles, los datos sacados están en blanco, adjunto el código:

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("1200x700")


def filtar_fecha():
        #este módulo para obtener la fecha de la date entry
        fecha0=str(fecha.get_date())
        
        # Clear the Treeview
        for record in arbol_tickets.get_children():#Limpia el árbol
            arbol_tickets.delete(record)
        #Base de datos
        conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
        cursor1=conn.cursor()
        comando="SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE  Fecha=%s"
        prov=(fecha0, )
        
        cursor1.execute(comando, prov)
        registro= cursor1.fetchall()
        print(registro)
        # Add our data to the screen
        global count
        count = 0

        for record in registro:
            if count % 2 == 0:
                arbol_tickets.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(count, record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7], record[8], record[9], record[10], record[11], record[12], record[13], record[14], record[15]), tags=('evenrow',))
            else:
                arbol_tickets.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(count, record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7], record[8], record[9], record[10], record[11], record[12], record[13], record[14], record[15]), tags=('oddrow',))
            # increment counter
            count += 1
            
bonton_filtrar=customtkinter.CTkButton(ventana, text="Filtrar", command=filtar_fecha)
bonton_filtrar.pack()

fecha=DateEntry(ventana, selectmode="day", date_pattern='mm/dd/yy')
fecha.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Un detalle, no puse el treeview para que el código no fuera tan largo, pero es irrelevante, lo importantes que que cuando la dunción imprime "registro", la lista está vacía. Recalco, el formato de fecha en la dateEntry y en los archivos de mysql es el mismo.
Cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Adjunto fotos de las fechas en la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit: Tengo una función para sacar un rango de fechas y usarlo como query. el problema es que la función solo acepta el método "get_date()" en los parámetros. Y su output es: año/mes/día, lo que no funcionará en el query. Si alguien sabe cómo corregirlo, gracias.

```
def date_range(start,stop):
    global dates # If you want to use this outside of functions
     
    dates = []
    diff = (stop-start).days
    for i in range(diff+1):
        day = start + timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(day)
    if dates:
    
        print(dates) # Print it, or even make it global to access it outside this
    

date1 =DateEntry(ventana_reportes)
date1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

date2 =DateEntry(ventana_reportes)
date2.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

date_range(date1.get_date(),date2.get_date())
```

Comment: Hice una prueba en dbfiddle donde la columna fecha de tipo date funciona bien pasando una fecha constante. Estás seguro de que ambos formatos son compatibles? El caracter que separa cada parte de la fecha también cuenta como parte del formato. Me mostrarias como es el formato de fecha en la columna fecha, y el formato de la fecha que pasas de parametro por favor?

Comment: Edit: Los caracteres separadores solo cuentan como parte del formato si la columna es de texto.

Comment: @DanteS. Hola Dante, disculpa que no te haya contestado, mi pc sigue dañada y solo puedo trabajar en la oficina. Adjunté fotos de los archivos en la base de datos para que puedas ver el formato de las fechas.

Comment: Procura poner la estructura _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Cuando imprimo la lista desde la terminas, imprime: ['10/25/22', '10/26/22', '11/03/22']

Comment: Primero que nada, te recomiendo seguir el consejo de Padaleiana, por que, de hecho [tiene razón](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880). Segundo, espero que te recuperes pronto de ese daño. Y tercero, ya se que está pasando, ahora te doy una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

De hecho no, los formatos de fecha son totalmente diferentes.

En tu base de datos, es `mm/dd/yy`. En cambio, lo que le mandas de parametro es de este formato:
`yy-mm-dd`.

¿Por que son diferentes? Por que el método `get_date` de DateEntry devuelve un objeto [datetime.date](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date), que es un objeto que representa una fecha. Si a eso lo conviertes en cadena, devuelve una cadena que es una fecha en formato `yy-mm-dd`.

#### La Solución más Simple

Podés tomar la cadena de fecha tal cual está en el entry usando el método `get` (heredado de ttk.Entry, la clase padre de DateEntry) y pasarsela a tu consulta, quedando tu función así:

```
fecha0=fecha.get()

# tu código antes de la consulta aquí

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha=%s", (fecha0,))

# tu código después de la consulta aquí
```

#### La Mejor Solución

Esta solución probablemente te costaría modificar toooodo tu programa, por lo que no la apliques, pero quizá te sirva para tener en cuenta más adelante.

Cuando trabajas con fechas, te conviene trabajar con el tipo DATE (o el tipo fecha especifico de tu base de datos), si existe. Esto tiene diversas ventajas:

- No necesitas lidiar o elegir un formato para tus fechas
- Puedes comparar las fechas como, bueno, fechas. Esto significa que puedes compararlas y ordenar columnas de fechas sin problemas. Si tu columna es, por ejemplo, de tipo string, entonces es posible que no obtengas el resultado esperado al ordenarlas o compararlas.
- Generalmente, los valores sql que sean de tipo date en Python se obtendrán como objetos datetime.date (los mismos antes mencionados), y será más facil trabajar con ellos por lo que son realmente, fechas.

Seguramente me digas ahora "todo genial, pero yo quiero mostrar esos objetos con un formato especifico". No te preocupes, muchas bases de datos ofrecen formas de darle formato a los tipos fecha. En mysql, esa sería la función [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

#### Pequeño consejo adicional

Python ofrece el [unpacking operator](https://geekflare.com/es/python-unpacking-operators/), que te ahorrará esas laaaargas lineas de `registro[1], registro[2], ...`

El código donde usas eso (asumiendo que puede haber más de 16 columnas y solo queremos las primeras 16) quedaría así:

```
arbol_tickets.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(count, *record[:16]), tags=('evenrow',))
```

Eso si, te recomiendo evitar hacer `select *` en el escenario en el que te encuentras, puede ser muy tentador que mysql "tome todas las columnas y ahorre esfuerzo", pero [hay varios motivos para no hacerlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322216/12913664) en el escenario en el que te encuentras.

Comment: hermano, funcionó. Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Un placer carlos c:

Comment: Hola Dante, edité la pregunta ya que surgió un nuevo problema, si pudieras revisarla (cuando puedas, por supuesto), gracias.

Comment: Tu segunda pregunta parece tener poca relación con la primera. Te recomiendo hacer tu pregunta en una nueva publicación. Stack Overflow está pensado para una sola pregunta por publicación. Además, así es más fácil para otros hallar la respuesta.

Comment: Hecho, no hay problema @DanteS.